# How can you hide grouped headers that have empty content when filtered? (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I want to display a list of tournaments that are grouped by year, but hide the year header if the filter eliminates all the tournaments within that year. Essentially not displaying the year if no tournaments will be rendered. Is there a way to do this?

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;" ng-repeat="(year, data) in tournamentListData | groupBy: 'year'">

  <span ng-show="(filter: {sportCD:tournamentSportFilter}).length > 0">
    {{year}}
    <hr />
  </span>

  <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="tournament in data | filter: {sportCD:tournamentSportFilter, organizationId:tournamentOrganizationFilter} | filter: tournamentSearchFilter">
    <a href="/tournament/{{ tournament.pk }}">{{ tournament.name }}</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the inner filter stuff out of the html and into your controller. Then you will know if any year has data under it and you can easily hide the header.